# After Graduation vs since Graduation

Tags: grammar

> (1). He has been running his own business since graduation.
>   (2). He has been running his own business after graduation.

I don't know the difference between "since graduation" and "after graduation" when referring to time.

Without given any date in each sentence, which of the above sentences implies that he has run his business at an earlier time? (1) or (2)?

Comment: We need more detail than what you've provided here... What is the question? What are your thoughts about which one is correct? If we understand what you are thinking, we can write a better answer.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the definitions of [since](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/since_1) and [after](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/after_1)? I probably wouldn't use "after" with "has been running" - I would use the simple past "He ran".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second sentence doesn't make sense. If you want to express a time frame you'd use the first.

**Sentence 1**

```
He has been running his own business since graduation.
```

This means he currently runs his own business, and he started running his own business at or very near graduation and is still running it today. This is emphasizing him running his business during the entire time-frame from graduation to present.

**Sentence 2**

```
He has been running his own business after graduation.
```

This doesn't make sense. *Has been running...* implies that this is an ongoing activity and to complete that sentence you'd need a continuous time-frame.

- He has been running his own business **for ten years.**
- He has been running his own business **since he was a child.**

The simple non-progressive moment in time "after graduation" is not a suitable tense. That would be like saying *He has been running his own business in January.* this is a verb tense confusion.

Comment: You could, however, have a perfectly grammatical and tense-agreed sentence with *He has been running his own business **since after** graduation.*

Comment: What about *He has been running his own business **from** graduation.* Would this be right?

Comment: @Phoenix From would imply where he was running his business. Like "...running his own business from Canada." So "from graduation" wouldn't make sense.